# execute bash script function with argument on remote server

Tags: bash

I have a local function [ check() ] in a script which takes argument [ check CCR] and stores the output into global variable [ $value ]. I would like to execute that function with the argument on a remote machine. This is what I have:

```
value=""

check() {
        exists=$(ps aux | grep "pf=" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $12}' | grep PT | grep $1 | tail -1 | awk -F= '{print $2}' | awk -F/ '{print $7}' | awk -F_ '{print $2}' | ( read x; echo ${x:0:3} ))

        if [ -z "$exists" ]; then
                value="false"
        elif [ $exists == $1 ]; then
                value="true"
        else
                value="false"
        fi
}

#check CCR
ssh remote@192.168.183.90 "$(typeset -f);check CCR"
echo $value
```

I am not getting any output back. please advise.

Comment: The global variable you set in that function is being set on the remote host. Of course you can't echo it on the local host. You can echo it from the remote host and capture it locally though.

Comment: like you said it does expose the other code and gives me back this error msg:

Badly placed ()'s.
{: Command not found.
Illegal variable name.
exists: Undefined variable.
value=false: Command not found.
else: endif not found.

How can i echo the response from remote and store it back in this script?

Comment: What gives you that error message? The `typeset -f` version you posted?

Comment: Yes the same script that i posted.

Comment: if i were to pipe the `typeset -f` instead : `typeset-f | ssh remote@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "$(cat); check CCR"`

I dont get any response back

Comment: That wouldn't materially change anything I don't think. Not to mention that the pipeline in that `check` function is **hideous** and could almost certainly be **greatly** simplified. Possibly even to just two commands (`pgrep` and `awk`).

Comment: I think the real solution here is to just run that pipeline as the remote ssh command and then do the checking on the local side. Assuming rewriting that pipeline isn't in the cards. Alternatively just running the `ps aux` on the remote end would also work and leave the rest of the pipeline being done locally.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can execute a multiline script like this:

```
ssh user@host <<'EOF'
function foo() {
    echo "hello $1"
}

foo bar
EOF
```

Comment: His code works correctly to execute the function on the remote end (but likely exposes a huge amount of other things to the remote end in the process) but that's not the problem the problem is the variable "scope".

Comment: Sure the variable scope is a problem, however wouldn't have expected that the function get's executed at all.. let me check that....

Comment: `typeset -f` dumps the current shell's functions into the string being executed on the remote host. Note the double quotes. The current shell expands that substitution first.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know `typeset`. Thanks!

Comment: @EtanReisner Wouldn't you say `typeset` is doing too much? Another thing. I was about to suggest that the function should echo the value instead of setting the variable, then I run into unexpected problems with the ssh banner message. It doesn't disappear as in commands which were type interactively.

Comment: `typeset` is just an alias for `declare` and yes I already did say it does too much for this purpose. What's the issue with the banner? Your host is spitting login/etc. information out to non-interactive sessions? That's not a good thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74738/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-etan-reisner).